# Get specific data from a webpage

Tags: c#, html-parsing

I have a [page](http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/loterias/ultimos_resultados.asp), and for that page I need to get the value from a other different page.

I just want to retrieve the 6 numbers into the "Números Sorteados" box.

So far I only succeeded in get the whole web page with this:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/loterias/ultimos_resultados.asp");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
string html = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
{
    html = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

After that, I can't select just these number from the HTML.

Comment: Have you considered using regular expressions?

Comment: Use HTMLAgilityPack to parse the html

Comment: If `html` contains HTML code then what you're looking for is a "DOM parser".  Something like the HTML Agility Pack should help.

Comment: @aochagavia please don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.

Comment: After inspecting the page it turns that that it's not that simple because the numbers are added to the page using JavaScript (through an AJAX call) as you can see [here](http://i.imgur.com/gK8uTBA.png)

Comment: Use CSQuery. It's like HTMLAgilityPack but better

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way to get the numbers using [HTMLAgilityPack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack):

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetNumbers()
{
    // Getting the number of microseconds since Jan 1st, 1970
    var microseconds = (long)(DateTime.UtcNow - (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))).TotalMilliseconds;
    // Creating the webrequest and passing the parameter
    var request =
        WebRequest.CreateHttp(
            string.Format(
                "http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/loterias/megasena/megasena_pesquisa_new.asp?app={0}",
                microseconds));
    // Adding a cookie container otherwise you will be stuck in a redirect loop
    var jar = new CookieContainer();
    request.CookieContainer = jar;

    try
    {
        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var html = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
            var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(html);
            var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span [@class=\"num_sorteio\"]");
            var numbersNodes = nodes.Last().SelectNodes("//li");

            // selecting the last 6 nodes that represent the "Números Sorteados" numbers
            return numbersNodes.Select(node => node.InnerText).Skip(6).ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // very basic exception handling.
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

and to call the function it's as easy as:

```
List<string> Numbers = await GetNumbers();
```