# C# HTML scraping between tags

Tags: c#

Okay so I'm trying to do a Skype tool which would have a "dictionary" command which would retrieve the meaning of the word from urban dictionary at the moment I'm able to load the whole HTML document in to string like this:

```
 private void urbanDictionary(string term)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=" + term);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string final_response = stream.ReadToEnd();

            MessageBox.Show(final_response);
        }
```

The problem is that I only want the meaning which is like so

```
<div class='meaning'> "meaning" </div>
```

I have tried all kinds of stuff but i cant manage to retrieve the text between "div" tags.

How could i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get specific data from a webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122891/get-specific-data-from-a-webpage)

Comment: What kinds of stuff have you really tried? This would be dead simple with HtmlAgilityPack or CsQuery (but stay away from regex!)

Comment: I do not think it is proper way to get meaning..since we can not be 100 % sure that class name will not changed by urbandictionary. If in future urbandictionary team changes structure or classname suddenly gets changed then you will not be able to get meanings.You will have to change the code again and again.

Comment: yeah im aware of that but "meaning" seems something what they would stick with but even if they change it, i have no problem to change my code later on, this is just for test purposes :)

Comment: hi, can you please accept my answer below to close this question, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use the HtmlAgilityPack library, exactly what you need.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659019/Scraping-HTML-DOM-elements-using-HtmlAgilityPack-H

Comment: I'd remove the suggestion about using regular expressions as regular expressions are for parsing regular text. HTML is **not** regular text. HTML Agility Pack is the right way to go 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest, in final_response string first find  then add create a substring from **that index**+**"div class='meaning'".length** to end of string. After in that substring find index position of "" and use this again to find another substring having text inbetween div tag.

Example.
IF you get  at index 100 then create substring using 100+38 to end.
This substring will like "meaning" .
Again find index position of  lets assume that it is 10 then find substring from 0 to (10 -1) this will give output as **meaning**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you're looking for. But I used https://www.mashape.com to get an API for urban dictionary. Unfortunatly it's unofficial, so I don't know for how long this will work. But as comments already mentioned, the html could also always change - most likely more often than an API. Also the API consumes less bandwidth, which should always preferred.

Usage would be

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("X-Mashape-Key", "APIKEY");
client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/plain");
Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString("https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.mashape.com/define?term="+ term));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

1) You can use Regex to remove the HTML tags. This is short and sweet and you can use it if the HTML source you are dealing with is not complex.

```
string meaningStr = Regex.Replace(final_response, @"<[^>]+>", "").Trim();
```

You can find the above solution tested live at: [regexstorm.net/tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3C%5B%5E%3E%5D%2B%3E&i=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%27meaning%27%3E%20%22meaning%22%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E&r=%22%22)

2) You can use HTMLAgilityPack . This method is recommended but needs you to expend some effort setting it up. With Nuget, it's not that difficult.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(final_response);
final_response = doc.InnerText;
```